# How to connect DIV to JavaScript changes

Tags: javascript

I need to change bottom DIV according to a slide show. So when the slide changes, the information at the bottom changes too!

I have the website online here: http://packageonly.tk/test

Currently the information will be shown once user clicks on FULL INFO 
But i need it automatically change once the slider goes to next.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XrOC.png)

here is the code for content change on mouseClick (Full info):

Comment: `.getElementById()` or `.getElementsByClassName()` etc. should target the element, but your question is so broad it's impossible to know exactly what you're looking for. Could you please state **which** DIV you want to target and how you want it to update. You'll also need to post your code in your question, rather than an external link.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using WordPress in conjunction with Avada theme. Also, please correct me if I am wrong but the slider you are using is a Rev Slider.

I believe in Rev Slider options, you have set an on click event to show the necessary tabs.

Go to the hover submenu in the slider options and define the action that you want to happen that would be to show the respective DIV elements.

Please go to the link below and you can find the relevant information.
Link: https://www.themepunch.com/faq/mouse-hovers-layer-content/

Comment: Exactly!!! I am using Avada and RevSlider. The problem is those thumbnails are being generated by RevSlider, so I dont have direct access to them..

Comment: @IvyKnm I can't access the page anymore, can you provide me with some more information of what are you referring to as thumbnails? Did you mean the yellow and red divs that were appearing on click?

Comment: those thumbnails you see - i dont have access to their properties...because they are being generated into <li> with the same class - no id is available. 
I dont know how to add onlick="function()" on those <li> tags..Revslider does let me to add it to the actual slider, or those texts (full info) but not those thumbnails

Comment: website is up tho - u should be able to open it.

Comment: Try this jQuery function and let me know if it helps.

$(".tp-mask-wrap").click(function(){
   $(this).children().css( "display", "none" );
  // setting the property of children elements to be none.
});

Comment: If you open the slider and click on the respective slide, right above the slider content you will see an action tab, click on that and you should be able to define the on click action or other types of actions.